# How does Promises work when JavaScript is single threaded?

Tags: javascript

How does JavaScript execute Promises async when JS is single threaded?
I know how to *use* Promises, but it is still unclear to me how it works behind the scene.

Comment: in simple terms, the callbacks for each outcome are stored in an array. when the deferred is resolved on some event, the callbacks are executed.

Comment: the same way setTimeout works.the execution is just deferred,doesnt need another thread to defer something.wether there is IO or not , a promise resolution or failure must be deferred,or it's not a promise.

Comment: see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Comment: asynchronous != multithreaded

Answer (score 2):

Promises are just a callback queue assigned to a lookup. Once you resolve the promise, it iterates over all callbacks which have been assigned via `then` or `done`.

Comment: A [littlebit *more* than callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), but yes - with the same limitations.